# Watching reputation points in the KDE system tray

Tags: discussion, reputation, addon

If you want to follow your reputation points in the KDE system tray, you might want to take a look at the BitBucket page of the
[StackOverflow KDE System Tray](http://bitbucket.org/richert/sotray/src/tip/sotray.py):

[image]

Requirements:

- KDE4
- PyKDE
- Python

You just need to set `USER_PAGE` to your StackOverflow profile page and start it.

And because it was not a question up to this point: What do you suggest how the program could be optimized? So far it definitely does not support Jon Skeet's rep points because of the size limitations.

**EDIT:** With unicode support and dynamic font scaling (Jon Skeet support)

Comment: Isn't this better on Stack Apps?

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ This is from 2009.

Comment: @NobodyNada I know, but since we have Stack Apps *now*, it's better there.

Answer (score 10):

The best optimization would be an alert saying "You are going nuts to follow your rep in real time, shut this down and take some big fat holidays with your girl...".

Or make a GTK GUI so GNOME people can enjoy it too.

Comment: Yeah, I voting for the first option. :)

Comment: You think anybody who wants to track their rep in real time has a girl?

Comment: Or just wants to experiment with PyKDE/KSystemTray ;-)

Comment: @Fred : life amazes me every day, so I stay opened :-)

Comment: Since both PyQt and PyKDE follow the systray protocol, the app works in KDE, Gnome, XFCE, ...

Comment: yes, but most of the gtk addicts will not be confortable with qt dependancies.

Answer (score 3):

First improvement might be to show both the stackoverflow + serverfault rep points?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty cool, how often do you refresh your information?

Comment: 3k rep and doesn't know what's an answer?

Comment: It is set as millisceonds in UPDATE_INTERVAL.

Answer (score 1):

What's the license? I'd like to write a GNOME equivalent and your Zip provides no COPYING or LICENSE file - nor does the source have a license at the top.

Comment: coming tomorrow with some refactorings that will ease your work

Comment: Great, waiting eagerly :)

Comment: Done. Maybe you merge you stuff into the current source so that the same file works both on GTK and KDE?

Comment: Great, will let you know what I've managed to do.

A couple of pointers - don't use `import *`, you'll get cyclic dependency issues which can be a real pain to debug. It's also better for code readability if you define what's being imported explicitly.

I'll email you with any further updates (and post here once I've gotten something concrete).

Comment: I have edited my initial question to now link to the according BitBucket page for that project. Feel free to contribute to that place.