# What happens to bounties awarded _to_ deleted users?

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-accounts

I just [learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/bounties-from-deleted-accounts-should-still-be-awarded-or-the-indicator-should-b) that bounties *from* deleted accounts are eliminated from history, with the argumentation that the awarded rep was gained by that user and not by the awarded one. But what about the other direction? Does the rep vanish? Is it refunded? Can it be re-awarded at least?

Comment: Assuming the rewarded answer is still there, despite its author being deleted?

Comment: @Arjan: yes, the answer is then owned by an anonymized shadow of that user (I mean, a gray unclickable user with the name last used before user deletion) [example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/watching-reputation-points-in-the-kde-system-tray) (though that's a migrated question, it looks the same for answers)

Comment: But then the awarded bounty, which was awarded *to an answer*, is still applicable? Why would the question owner be refunded, or be able to award it to another answer?

Comment: @Arjan: True. I was just wondering, since for the other direction reputation is not considered transferred but more or less borrowed only - so with the recipient vanishing my false deduction was it can't vanish. But stating "the bounty is awarded to the _answer_, not the user" is the answer, since the bounty doesn't actually vanish as long as the answer is left

Comment: @Tobias the bounty that stays there is a bug as far as I understood the question you linked to - the **bounty** is given on answer, but the **reputation** goes to some specific member..

Comment: On the other hand: it would make some sense to refund (or at least make it available again for a new 7 day period), *if* [Bounties from deleted accounts should still be awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/bounties-from-deleted-accounts-should-still-be-awarded) is not considered to be a bug. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, two questions with two answers.

1. > > Does the rep vanish?
   > >     Yes because deleted user can't have any reputation.. whatever reputation he got goes to the grave with his account.
2. > > Is it refunded / Can it be re-awarded
   > >     No, in the [bounty wiki page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) it clearly says:
   > >     Please note that once a bounty is started, the reputation is non-refundable under any circumstances

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - Just curious - What if that user creates an account again with same OpenID as before deletion? Then will he get his rep back?

Comment: re 1) I heard all deleted-user rep is actually transferred to the community user who is hard-coded to show up with 1 rep only. uhm, not that it really matters...

Comment: @Sachin - they will not, the record of that previous user is gone...so that OpenID no longer has *any* relation to the bounty :)

Comment: @Sachin To tack onto Nick's note,  in extenuating circumstances it is possible for the user to be merged with a deleted account, this is used to restore deletion in the scenario that a user does return. As this reverts a lot, I would expect bounties to also be affected by it.

Comment: @Nick is the record "hard deleted" / purged from database, or can it be recovered per Grace comment?

Comment: @Tobias, Community hardcoded to show 1? [Not so much!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come)

Comment: @Grace - this isn't the case, since the bounty (technically a vote) is transferred to the community user when the user's deleted...while we can make an educated guess here, it's not something that would happen, no.

Comment: @Arjan: thanks for the link, I only looked at their meta account. Interesting

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the confirmation. I was under the impression that the votes were reverted as well, but perhaps it's only the winnings.

Comment: @Grace - That's mostly accurate...only in the case of bounties specifically we transfer them to community to ensure there are no issues in awarding them.

Comment: just as a prove: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l/43001#43001) by a deleted user still has a bounty rewarded